# from selenium to excel

Tags: excel, selenium, beautifulsoup

The code below uses selenium to scrape some data and prints the results to the screen.  Would anyone know how I could save this data to an excel file and even better to a sheet in an already existing file?  Thanks

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

url = 'http://www.tradingview.com/screener'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

try:

    selector = '.js-field-total.tv-screener-table__field-value--total'
    condition = EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector))
    matches = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(condition)
    matches = int(matches.text.split()[0])

except (TimeoutException, Exception):
    print ('Problem finding matches, setting default...')
    matches = 4895 # Set default

# The page loads 150 rows at a time; divide matches by
# 150 to determine the number of times we need to scroll;
# add 5 extra scrolls just to be sure
num_loops = int(matches / 150 + 5)

for _ in range(num_loops):

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    sleep(2) # Pause briefly to allow loading time

# will give a list of all tickers
tickers = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.tv-screener__symbol') 

# will give a list of all EMPs
emps = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[10]')

# will give a list of all sectors
sectors = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[11]')

for index in range(len(tickers)):
   print("Row " + tickers[index].text + " " + emps[index].text + " " + sectors[index].text + " ")
```

Comment: That's great that you've given us some code, but as far as I can tell it's not relevant to the issue you're having, which is that you want to write the data generated from the code to an excel spreadsheet. What have you tried to solve this particular problem?

Comment: It's very confusing to even know which is the best way to do it. What do you recommend?

Comment: I installed openpyxl on Anaconda. Been trying to understand how to use it but it's really brutal.  Can anyone get me started?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use an external api/framework. For java I use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) to save my selenium data to excel.

I've yet to do it in python but there are some great resources [here](http://www.python-excel.org/).